# Reload/Refresh div content without reloading whole page (with time interval)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im am using a wordpress plugin that shows a scheduled of what dj is on air now. But the issue is if a person is on a page while the dj changes it does not auto refresh the content within the div. Is there a way I can auto refresh the content within the div using a time interval.

i Should Explain a bit more. Here is the div with the shortcode within it. All I need is for the dive to reload the shortcode inside it.

```
<div class="little-head-2" style="margin-top:15px;"><?php echo do_shortcode('[dj-widget]');?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax's `load()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp) function wrapped inside a [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) could work for this, adjust interval time as desired:

Create a `.php` file with:

```
echo do_shortcode('[dj-widget]');
```

Then on your JS load it via ajax with a time interval of half a minute or whatever:

```
setInterval(djReload, 30000); //30000 ms = 30 seconds

function djReload() {
    $('.little-head-2').load('fileCreated.php');
}
```

Comment: i Should Explain a bit more. Here is the div with the shortcode within it. All I need is for the dive to reload the shortcode inside it.<div class="little-head-2" style="margin-top:15px;"><?php echo do_shortcode('[dj-widget]');?>
      </div>